# akka-http HttpEntity.toStrict timed out while still waiting for outstanding data

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I encounter a problem randomly without SSL(sometimes it works without issue), and each time with SSL, and I don't understand why. 
It's a time out during HttpEntity.toStrict.

```
extractRequest{payload =>

              val futureRequestEntity = payload.entity.toStrict(5.seconds).map(_.data.utf8String)
              val requestEntity = Await.result(futureRequestEntity, 10.seconds)

... }
```

I tried to set longer waiting times, but doesn't solve the issue.

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: HttpEntity.toStrict timed out after 5 seconds while still waiting for outstanding data
at akka.http.impl.util.ToStrict$$anon$1.onTimer(package.scala:138)
```

I need to use extractRequest for my path because I extract the entity and the header further in the code.

Route code :

```
            options {
          corsHandler.corsHandler(complete(StatusCodes.OK))
        } ~ post {
          path("recommandation" / Segment / Segment / "suggestion") {(docType,docId) =>
            extractRequest{payload =>
              writeLog("info",s"/recommandation : Post request for $docType suggestion : $docId ")
              val coBranding = payload.headers.filter(x => x.is("cobrandingcontext")).map(x => x.value()).head
              val futureRequestEntity = payload.entity.toStrict(5.seconds).map(_.data.utf8String)
              val requestEntity = Await.result(futureRequestEntity, 10.seconds)

              val parsedPayload = suggestionEngine.payloadParser.suggestionEnginePayloadParser(requestEntity,
                coBranding,docType, docId)
              if (parsedPayload.isDefined){
                val suggestionResult = suggestionEngine.suggestionWorker.suggestionPipeline(parsedPayload.get)
                val suggestionResponse = suggestionEngine.responseHandler.responseBuilder(suggestionResult).get
                complete(200,List(`Content-Type`(`application/json`)),suggestionResponse)

              } else {
                writeLog("error","/recommandation : undefined payload")
                complete(StatusCodes.BadRequest,List(`Content-Type`(`application/json`)),"Undefined payload")
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

Request example :

```
    curl -i https://mydns.com:443/recommandation/products/59ad73be20a35d3fa47c80c8/suggestion -H 
  'cobrandingcontext: branding' -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' -X POST -d '{"collection":"products",
  "query":{"category_parent":"category-ex","category_child":"category-child-ex","dimensions.width":{"$lt":70,"$gt":0},
  "dimensions":{"$lt":40,"$gt":-40},"status":true,"structured":true,"visibilities":"architects-3d-btoc"},"configuration":{"type":"nearest-neighbors","metric":"cosine","features":["styles"]}}'
```

Thank's in advance

Comment: Please, provide more detailed description about request you receive and it's size. I have a feeling, that it is highly likely that it is too big to be parsed in give time. Thanks!

Comment: I edit it with what you ask, 
But I don't think it's too big because it works well randomly (without ssl).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the explanation is that the use of Await will block a dispatcher thread which can lead to thread starvation.
The solution I found is to nest directives  :

```
                options {
              corsHandler.corsHandler(complete(StatusCodes.OK))
            } ~ post {
              path("/"){
                entity(as[String]){payload =>
                  headerValueByName("context"){ contextValue => {
...// work with payload and contextValue

                   }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
```